# Where to set static member's properties?

Tags: c#, static, static-members

If I have a static member variable in my class, where should I initialize it, and set all of its properties?

```
class Foo
{
    static public Timer t;
    private int foo;

    public Foo(int f)
    {
        this.foo = f;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my class has member variable `private int foo` which is set to match the constructor's parameter. I also got `static public Timer t` which is supposed to tick for each isntance of this class. Now my question is, where should I add this code:

```
t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1;
```

Since if I add it to my class' constructor, it will be called every time when a new instance is created, which is not what I want. I could move the `t = new Timer();` to the actual variable declaration like so: `static public Timer t = new Timer();` but I would still have to insert `t.Interval = 1;` somewhere.

So the question is, how do I initialize a static member - and how do I edit its properties - only once, and not every time I create a new instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give you slightly different advice from most of the other replies.

I'm saying that you should avoid a static constructor if possible.

The reason is one of efficiency. The details are too complex to go into here, but see these pages for details:

http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/17/115300.aspx?Redirected=true

To be honest, it's probably not too much to worry about, but because it's so simple to avoid a static constructor, you should probably do so.

What you do is to write a static method which will return a value with which you can initialise your static field.

For your Timer example it would look like this:

```
private static Timer _timer = InitTimer();

private static Timer InitTimer()
{
    Timer result = new Timer {Interval = 100};
    return result;
}
```

Although for a simple initialisation like that, it's not even necessary to write a separate method, since you can just do this:

```
private static Timer _timer = new Timer {Interval = 100};
```

But in more complex situations, you can write a static method.

Comment: That's interesting, links were useful too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in a [Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), like this:

```
static Foo()
{
    t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 1;
}
```

From MSDN:

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs performed once only. It is
>   **called automatically** before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

Comment: Can I have both `static` AND `public` constructor in one class?

Comment: Yes you can. The static you'll be called automatically. And the non-static will be called each time you instantiate a new object

Answer (score 2):

[Static Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are used for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are static constructors. Invoke them like this

```
class Foo {

static Foo(){
// initialize your timer here
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do this:

### Initialiser

```
static public Timer t = new Timer
{
    Interval = 1
};
```

### Static constructor

```
static public Timer t;

static Foo
{
    t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 1;
}
```